# Ошибки при включении консоли mongo

Tags: mongodb

Когда включаю консоль mongo вылезают ошибки

```
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-07-07T11:41:36.073+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Что делать ?

Comment: Собственно это не ошибки, это предупреждения. Работать будет и с ними, но как поправить, тоже бы с удовольствием послушал.

Answer (score 2):

Временно изменить их можно так (значения потеряются после перезагрузки системы):

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

Изменить их постоянно можно, добавив в файл `/etc/sysfs.conf` следующие строки:

```
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled = never
kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag = never
```

Comment: Сделал, то что вы написали, но мне не помогло